# axios.delete() not running then block

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, http-delete

I have a small application with react, express and mongo. GET and POST requests work perfectly fine with axios.  The DELETE request works with the backend and actually deletes the item in the mongo database. Code snippet:

```
 deleteTodo = (event) => {
    const url = "http://localhost:4000/dashboard";
    const id = event.target.parentElement.getAttribute("data-id");
    const deleteUrl = `${url}/${id}`;

    axios.delete(deleteUrl)
        .then(res => {
            console.log("deleted")
        });
}
```

But nothing is happening afterwards, I don't get "deleted" message in the console. I tried console.log, setState and so on, none of these functions is triggered in the .then.

Comment: What if you `.catch`?

Comment: what does console says ? what do you see in network tab ?

Comment: Post a self-answer instead of editing your question. As long as your answer and question both are on-topic and otherwise acceptable by SO standards, it's not just accepted - [it's recommended](/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I changed code in the delete method of the server.js and it somehow works now. From:

```
app.delete("/dashboard/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Item.findById(id)
    .then(item => item.remove())            
});
```

To:

```
app.delete("/dashboard/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Item.findById(id)
    .then(item => item.remove()
        .then(() => res.json({ success: true })))
    .catch(err => res.send("Error"))
});
```